# Javascript using variable as key to get nested object value

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Assume I have the following object:

```
var jsonObj = {  
  "response":{  
    "result":{  
      "status":{
        "name": "Eric"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now i'd like to dynamically access a nested property:

```
jsonKey = "response.result.status.name";
console.log("the status is: " + jsonObj.jsonKey);  //I cannot call jsonObj.jsonKey here
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: this -> `jsonObj[jsonValue]`

Comment: @btzr Even if this is my jsonValue? `response.result.status.name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: is that a string  (`status.name`) ?

Comment: What is the result when you console log `jsonObj`?

Comment: @btzr Yes, the value returns a string.

Comment: then yes, see this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4244912/6836839

Comment: if `status.name == "theKey"` then this are the same:                    `obj.theKey == obj[status.name] == obj["theKey"]` ^^

Comment: mozilla docs: [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: @btzr I added my jsonObj above, you mentioned if `status.name` is a string or not. What if it isn't a string?

Comment: did you read the links?

Comment: you are trying to access to an object property by the name, right?

Comment: @btzr Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167130/discussion-between-btzr-and-kkmoslehpour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access a deeply nested property as simple as you expect. Instead you need to use the `obj[propertyNameAsString]` syntax to dive deeper into the response one by one.

This would be one way of getting there:

```js
let response = {
  "response": {
    "method": "GetStatus",
    "module": "Module",
    "data": null,
    "result": {
      "status": {
        "name": "Eric"
      },
      "id": 1
    },
    "result_code": {
      "error_code": 0
    }
  }
}

let keyString = "response.result.status.name"
let keyArray = keyString.split('.'); // [ "response", "result", "status", "name" ]
var result = response;

for (key of keyArray) {
  result = result[key]
}

console.log(result)
```

**Please be aware that this is not failsafe against cases where one of those strings in `keyArray` does not exist as a property on the preceding object.**

Comment: Ah, i see now. This makes much more sense! Thank you !

Comment: this breaks in some cases (like objects being null). the question posted by @btzr constains an answer with a safer implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45322101/347508

Comment: even object can be like {a : { "my-key": "my-value"}}

Answer (score -1):

You can use code like this:

```
something['bar']
```

Where bar is your variable that has been converted to string, in our case:

```
jsonObj[`${jsonKey}`]
```

Comment: Why are you using string interpolation on the key, rather than just using the key variable directly as `jsonObj[jsonKey]`?